# CDI (weld 3.0.3.Final) not calling @PostConstruct if @ApplicationScope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, weld, jboss-weld

I ran into a bit of an interesting problem as I was going through my latest application and working on coverting beans to @ApplicationScope since I really only needed 1 instance.

I have a couple classes I created to inject values from a properties file.  I inject like this:

```
@Inject @Conf("key.in.properties.file")
protected String value;
```

The @Conf annotation is simple:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Conf {
    @Nonbinding
    String value() default "";
}
```

The I created a producer class with a @PostConstruct method to load the properties file.  I've confirmed that when making this @ApplicationScope, the @PostConstruct method is no longer called.  This is not a matter of lazy loading.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfPropertyProducer {

    private Properties props;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(ConfDirectory confDirectory) {
        props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(new File(confDirectory, "conf.properties")));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @Conf
    public String produceStringProperty(InjectionPoint ip) {
        Conf m = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Conf.class);
        if (props == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("WHY IS PROPS NULL?");
        }
        return props.getProperty(m.value(), "-UNKNOWN-").trim();
    }
}
```

As a work around, I had to get rid of the @PostConstruct method and convert it into a class constructor.

When nothing is @ApplicationScope and instead relies on CDI's default @Dependant scope, it works fine.  But I'm not sure why this @PostConstruct method is never called. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your `@PostConstruct` method definition is invalid - you cannot have any parameters there. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html).

The way you had it means you were using it in an undefined way. Hence it's hard to guess why it worked in one way and not in the other or why it worked at all. And probably not worth guessing at all.

Note - if you need to do some injection prior to post construct invocation, the go-to way is to have a constructor injection with it. You will still need one no-arg dummy constructor for the sake of proxy creation.